# How to apply specific "compilerOptions" to specific file only? (tsconfig.json)

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

Is it possible that apply specific tsconfig options to 1 file only?

Below is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "keyofStringsOnly": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  ...
}
```

I would like to use option "resolveJsonModule" and "esModuleInterop" in specify component file only.

Is there any way for this? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must create a new tsconfig.ts file inside the directory where is your especial file. You can use **extends** if you can reuse original options, or you can modify some options on it:

Example:

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false
    }
}
```

NOTE: Maybe you need to restart your code editor to force read again typescript conditions.